# MongoDB extract values from deeply nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

as a result of this aggregate

```js
[
            {
                $match: {userId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)}
            },
            {
                $project: {translations: 1}
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'menus',
                    localField: '_id',
                    foreignField: 'restaurantId',
                    as: 'menus'
                }
            }
```

I have the following data structure:

```json
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("62642181334359e4c7204af3"),
    translations: [ 'it', 'en' ],
    menus: []
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("626421f0334359e4c7204afe"),
    translations: [ 'en' ],
    menus: [ 
        { 
            structure: [ 
                [], 
                [ 
                    { dishId: new ObjectId("613e22455c6cf380b819d131") } 
                ], 
                [], 
                [] 
            ] 
        } 
    ]
  }
]
```

How should I modify my aggregate so that I end up with the following data structure instead?

```json
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("62642181334359e4c7204af3"),
    translations: [ 'it', 'en' ],
    dishIds: []
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("626421f0334359e4c7204afe"),
    translations: [ 'en' ],
    dishIds: [ 
        new ObjectId("613e22455c6cf380b819d131")
    ]
  }
]
```

I've tried using $map and $reduce, but I can't figure out how to combine them properly.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Found out about the $function operator and solved the problem by adding the following to my aggregate:

```js
{
                $project: {
                    dishIds: {
                        $function: {
                            body: function(menus){
                                return [].concat(...menus.map((m) => [].concat(...m.structure))).map((d) => d.dishId.str);
                            },
                            args: ['$menus'], 
                            lang: 'js'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

where

```js
[].concat(...array)
```

flattens an array containing other arrays.

Not sure if using $function operator is as efficient as using other mongodb operators though.